# access css property value

Tags: javascript

```
function getSitePallete(Selector) {
    var Selectors = document.styleSheets[8].rules;
    var pallete = new Array();    
    for (var i = 0; i < Selectors.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < Selectors[i].style.length; j++) {
            if (Selectors[i].style[j] == "color")
                // here i want the value of color property (like if color : #ffffff so i want #ffffff )
        }
    }
}
```

I want to access the value of color property.How can i access it?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What are you trying to achieve? Using `document.styleSheets` is inefficient, I'd like to know if there is a better way.

Comment: I want to get all the color available on the website

Comment: I will show the pallete to user and user will change any color they want

Comment: Are you trying to build something like [The Colour Bookmark](http://wearepandr.com/labs/colour_bookmark)?

Comment: No , but if u tell me the solution for my problem then it will more helpful for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this site ( http://htmlbook.ru/css/color ) says that color CSS property can be acessed via following DOM code

```
[window.]document.getElementById("elementID").style.color
```

I think you can adopt this to your needs.